# SPNEGO authentication with Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, spnego, htmlunit-driver

I have SPNEGO authentication for my applications and am doing automated testing using selenium HtmlUnitDriver.

I have tried running the browser automation code inside login context of SPNEGO authentication, but it seems like it is not working,

The body of the lambda is in authentication context already. And SPNEGO is working for REST calls, but not for HtmlUnitDriver.

```java
myACtion -> {
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.navigate().to(url);

}
 Subject.doAs(loginContext.getSubject(), myAction);
```

If someone can tell me how to use SPNEGO keytab authentication with HtmlUnitDriver in selenium, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support so far.
If you like to see this supported i can offer this:

- implement a complete working minimal sample using only org.apache.httpcomponents 4.5.10 (maybe this might help https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)
- open a HtmlUnit issue on github and provide your sample code
- i will add the required support to HtmlUnit